# Expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int"

Tags: arrays, c

while printing 3d array in the below code,  it shows error: expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int"

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printarray(int *arr,int n,int x,int y,int z);
int main()
{int x=2,y=3,z=4;
    int a[x][y][z];         // here [2] represents two times of 3*4 2d array
    a[x][y][z]={
                {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
                {{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
               }           //or simply {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof[1];
    void printarray(a,n,x,y,z);
return 0;

}
void printarray(int *arr,int n,int x,int y,int z)
{
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<z;k++)
            {
                printf("%d ",arr[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
return ;
}
```

Comment: If you call `printarray` (instead of declaring it), gcc gives a useful warning: `note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[y][z]’`

Comment: `a[x][y][z]` is a single int and is out of bounds on all 3 indices. You can't assign to  the array like that. Normally I'd say initialize it, but you also can't initialize variable length arrays.

Comment: Flattening a multidimensional array this way is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to use constants (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) then you initialize the fixed size array `a`.  It will zero initialize the ones not specified.

You cannot initialize the vla `b` so you would have to use a bunch of assignments, memset and/or memset with a temporary variable.  I all 3 options here to demonstrate usage.  Note it's undefined behavior if you miss an assignment.

Then use a vla for the function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define X 2
#define Y 3
#define Z 4

void printarray(int x,int y,int z, int arr[x][y][z]) {
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<z; k++)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j][k]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int a[X][Y][Z] = {
        {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},
        {{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
    };
    printarray(X, Y, Z, a);

    int x = X, y = Y, z = Z;
    int b[x][y][z];
    b[0][0][0] = 1;
    b[0][0][1] = 2;
    b[0][0][2] = 3;
    b[0][0][3] = 0;
    b[0][1][0] = 4;
    b[0][1][1] = 5;
    b[0][1][2] = 6;
    b[0][1][3] = 0;
    b[0][2][0] = 0;
    b[0][2][1] = 0;
    b[0][2][2] = 0;
    b[0][2][3] = 0;
    memcpy(b[1][0], (int []) {7, 8, 9, 0}, sizeof **b);
    memcpy(b[1][1], (int []) {10, 11, 12, 0}, sizeof **b);
    memset(b[1][2], 0, sizeof **b);
    printarray(x, y, z, b);
}
```

and here is the resulting output:

```
1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 0 10 11 12 0 0 0 0 0
1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 0 10 11 12 0 0 0 0 0
```